# rgb to change opacity in Matlab for a big graph

Tags: matlab

I had a problem with RGB in matlab, i think i have a big graph that's why there it is [my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PinQ4.png)

i have tried this method

```
yy=plot(Xlink,Ylink,'color',rgb('light blue'),'MarkerSize',25);
```

but i have had this problem

```
Undefined function or variable 'rgb'.

Error in testrect (line 200)
yy=plot(Xlink,Ylink,'color',rgb('light blue'),'MarkerSize',25);
```

And i have tried the simple way of color

```
yy=plot(Xlink,Ylink,'MarkerSize',25);
 yy.Color=[255 255 255]./255;
```

i have had this problem

```
Undefined function or variable 'rgb'.

Error in testrect (line 200)
yy=plot(Xlink,Ylink,'color',rgb('light blue'),'MarkerSize',25);
```

Comment: The second error message is the same one as the first, cannot be related to the second command. Please double-check you copied the correct message.

Comment: Your second attempt should have worked. I don't see a problem with it. Why do you refer to "opacity" in the title? To set opacity you need to adjust, I think, the 'alpha' property of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use the `rgb` function from this File exchange submission: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46872-intuitive-rgb-color-values-from-xkcd

This is not a built-in function. You need to download it from the link above and install it to a directory on your MATLAB path. Actually, you can install it to any directory and add that directory to your path using the `addpath` function. You can also copy that file to your current directory, but it will only be available as long as you don't move to a different directory.